# How to make a AWS lambda function with public access using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to create a `AWS lambda function` with public access without any authorization via `serverless`. In my API witch I have all functions with a private access via authorizer. I tried to deploy the function without authorizer but it gives me `403 Forbidden`.

My function example:

```yaml
    rel-Session:
    description: do something public
    handler: src/handlers/items/getNewPublicItem.getNewPublicItem
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/v1.0/public/item/{id}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
          cors:
            origin: ${env:CorsAllowOrigin}
```

How can I make my endpoint to be with public access?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your API, not the Lambda function. You can make your api available to the public with an API key or by configuring identity pools with AWS Cognito. It would all depend on what you're using for authentication. Here's a serverless template for attaching a lambda function to run based on an API method:

https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-lambda-function-as-api-gateway-endpoint

Here's AWS docs on configuring an API Key:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html